# How to delete a GCP Resource Folder programatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler, google-cloud-resource-manager

I am trying to create a cron service that cleans up (removes billing and deletes) a bunch of projects and resource folders on GCP for a development team. Ideally, I would like to use cloud functions to do this as its lightweight, however, **I can't seem to find any client libraries that would allow for FOLDER deletion**. **Has anyone been able to find any client libraries to do this?**

The other options I am considering are:

- To create a Cloud Run cron service in a container which calls gcloud
  commands (like this
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/resource-manager/folders/create).
- Call the GCP Rest API from the cloud function to the resource manager
  APIS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the discovery API. We use it in production (only for search and then attach project to a folder)

An example of our python code

```
from googleapiclient import discovery 
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

#Use GCF Service Account credentials for all APIs call
CREDENTIALS = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

SERVICE_RESOURCE_MANAGER_FOLDER = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v2', 
                                                    credentials=CREDENTIALS)

# Example for a search
    request = SERVICE_RESOURCE_MANAGER_FOLDER.folders().search(body=body)
    response = request.execute()
```

Use the [delete operation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v2/folders/delete) if you want to do this.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah I finally figured out how to use it, hadn't used discovery API before.